# What is the purpose of * in java.io.*

Tags: java, io

What is the purpose of the * in java.io.*?

```
import java.io.*;
class Trial{
     public static void main(String[]args){
         System.out.println("Hello,World!");
     }
}
```

Comment: It will import all classes from java.io.

Comment: I am not being able to find: "require minimum understanding of the problem being solved". I was searching it: because the way you asked(including your code) tells me that you want to know about packaging system of java but yet the question is vague(asking about purpose of a specific import!)

Comment: @Sage: reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple misunderstanding on the OP's part, that has nothing to do with I/O.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of \* in Import Statement in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897448/use-of-in-import-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star indicates that all classes from the java.io package should be imported.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` tells the compiler to import all top-level classes in [`java.io`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) on demand. The construct is called a *type-import-on-demand* declaration.

From [JLS §7.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2):

> A *type-import-on-demand* declaration allows all accessible types of a named package or type to be imported as needed.
>
> ```
> TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration:
>     import PackageOrTypeName . * ;
> ```

So, for example, since you've included that import statement, you can use a class like `java.io.File` without having to prefix the type name with `java.io`; you can use the simple name `File`.

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard in a package name `import` is used to include all the classes contained in that specific package. Check [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

In addition you are able to import inner static classes to be able to refer to them without a fully qualified name, eg:

```
import org.package.MyClass;

//MyClass.InnerClass inner; not needed
InnerClass inner;
```