# Java import statement with * not picking up class

Tags: java

(Disclaimer: I am new to Java and also, I have read the related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897448/use-of-in-import-statement-in-java).)

I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
...
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
```

But the `PDFont` class is not recognized in Eclipse.

When I add the following:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
```

The `PDFont` class is picked up.

Given that the `PDFont` class is located under the hierarchy specified in the first import statement ending with the asterisk, why is a specific import statement necessary?

Also, is there a way to search for the location of a class in a library if one doesn't have the documentation handy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The on demand `import` declarations are not recursive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)

> A type-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible types of a
>   named package or type to be imported as needed.

Your `PDFont` type is in package

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font
```

but you've tried to import

```
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
```

the package `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel` does not contain a type named `PDFont`.

So, alternatively, you could have used

```
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.*;
```

---

> Also, is there a way to search for the location of a class in a
>   library if one doesn't have the documentation handy?

If the library is published as a `.jar`, you can unzip it and search through it.

Most IDEs typically have a feature to search types by their simple name. For example, in Eclipse, you can use `CTRL (cmd) + SHIFT + T` and type the simple or fully qualified name to search for (if it's on the classpath).

Comment: I see, it only picks up what's at that level (pdmodel) and does not recurse.  Thanks so much, will accept when SO let's me.

Comment: @Sabuncu It's important to note that there is no inherent hierarchy in `package` names. It's just easier for developers to "nest" them like that.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  What about my second (minor) question? ;-)

Comment: Unbelievable! Can't thank you enough, I wish I could upvote more. (Yahoo is very lucky!)

Comment: Isn't it better to use the IDE to import the necessary classes and also let the IDE remove them when there are no dependencies left? I can't seem understand why it would make much sense to import all classes in a directory when using an IDE.

Comment: @Sabuncu As Joop is suggesting, you can also use, again in Eclipse, `CTRL + SHIFT + o` to let your IDE manage your `import` statements. It will clean up anything unnecessary.

Comment: @Joop As I mentioned, I am new to Java, and the code is not mine, but from a tutorial.  When I modified the tutorial to add new code, the problem surfaced.

Comment: Yes, just tried `CTRL + SHIFT + o` and it filled in everything for me! What is the name of this shortcut (i.e. its location in the menu structure)?

Comment: @Sabuncu Something like "Organize imports".

Comment: @Joop In my opinion, it is not better to have the IDE automatically handle import statements.  Many times it saves some effort, but when it doesn't save effort you get into a fight with your IDE's auto-completion abilities.  I'm for an IDE than can do it if requested, just don't ever have it cleaning up imports without a command.  Otherwise, you can inadvertently get the wrong imports for classes which have similar names but different packages, and then to fix that watch yourself killing an import statement just to see yet another wrong one come into play.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Good to know that auto-importing does not always happens correctly. I have yet to experience that though, but good to know that it could. When I said automatic I meant semi-automatic so I didn't mean that the IDE would insert it without asking or suggesting an import, or using a shortcut. Thank you for your perspective.